# How to sum numbers with parent and child process using fork()

Tags: c, linux, fork, wait

I have to add two of the result made by the different process. First, add from 1 to 100 in the certain child process. Next, add 101 to 200 in that process`s parent process. After that, I want to get a sum of that two results using fork() and wait(). I want this final process should be done in the parent process. I wonder that how can I toss the result of the sum of 1-100 to the parent process. Should I use a special Linux command or function? Anyone have a nice idea, please give a solution to me! Hope to get a positive reply!

```c
//child process
for(i = 1 to 100)
sum += i;
```

```c
//parent process
for(i = 101 to 200)
sum += i;

//parent process??? or not
print("sum 1 to 200"= ???)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared memory, pipe, file, domain socket, etc.
or use multithreading

```
int *sum;
sum=(int *)mmap(NULL, sizeof(int)*count_of_process, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
                MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
```